# bash: Bad Substitution

Tags: string, bash, ubuntu, substitution

```
#!/bin/bash

jobname="job_201312161447_0003"
jobname_pre=${jobname:0:16}
jobname_post=${jobname:17}
```

This bash script gives me *Bad substitution* error on Ubuntu. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is working fine to me. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to divide the jobname into two: job_201312161447 and 0003. Its giving this error only when I am trying to run this on ubuntu.

Comment: Mmmm strange. What if you use `cut`? `cut -d_ -f1,2 <<< "$jobname"` and `cut -d_ -f3 <<< "$jobname"` make it

Comment: thanks. but why jobname_pre=${jobname:0:16} gave error

Comment: @bludger you are right, I see that if you do `sh script.sh` it gets a "Bad substitution" error.

Comment: @fedorqui cool. Added it as an answer.

Comment: Lots of alternative solutions: [`http://askubuntu.com/questions/571852/alternatives-for-variable-string-substitution-in-bash`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/571852/alternatives-for-variable-string-substitution-in-bash)

Answer (score 308, accepted):

The default shell (`/bin/sh`) under Ubuntu points to `dash`, not `bash`.

```
me@pc:~$ readlink -f $(which sh)
/bin/dash
```

So if you `chmod +x your_script_file.sh` and then run it with `./your_script_file.sh`, or if you run it with `bash your_script_file.sh`, it should work fine.

Running it with `sh your_script_file.sh` will not work because the hashbang line will be ignored and the script will be interpreted by `dash`, which does not support that string substitution syntax.

Comment: @DanFromGermany because that's the only reason for that error, i.e. he's running the script in a way that doesn't consider the hashbang, and that bash syntax is not supported by some other shell (probably dash). Questions don't always contain all the needed details, and we must join the dots... anyway feel free to downvote my answer.

Comment: I dont need to downvote. I have the same error message `bad substitution` and I'm just trying to gather information but this question doesn't help because it has too few information.

Comment: @DanFromGermany you could try posting your own question, maybe it's not exactly the same problem.

Comment: and I was using `zsh` :facepalm:

Comment: Thanks for this!  I just got bit by this too.  Just what we needed: another shell program with subtle quirks that make it fit on a 5.25 inch disk.

Answer (score 121):

I had the same problem. Make sure your script didnt have

```
#!/bin/sh
```

at the top of your script. Instead, you should add

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: I used `#!bin/bash` and `sh script.sh`, it still gave me the error message. Then `./script.sh` works.

Comment: If your file is missing a shebang at the top adding `#!/bin/bash` will also fix the *Bad substitution*.

Comment: @whyisyoung your variable could be having a dot (.) in its name. It gives bad subst. error.

Comment: @whyisyoung the `#!` line is used only when you execute your script directly. If you use `sh script.sh` the line is completely ignored.

Comment: yes, got same issue on Ubuntu because it default using  dash to run script.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me, I had a #!/bin/sh at the top of my script (erroneously), under centos doing ./myscript.sh it ignored the shebang, ran it under bash, and it worked. In Ubuntu it ran it (correctly) in /bin/sh and failed.

Answer (score 106):

For others that arrive here, this exact message will also appear when using the env variable syntax for commands, for example `${which sh}` instead of the correct `$(which sh)`

Comment: The difference is curly brace `{` vs normal bracket `(` (took me a little time to figure out what you were showing)

Comment: This was my issue with a similar problem. Was reviewing different bash script examples from StackExchange and copy/paste resulted in this disconnect. Curly braces needed to be substituted and it all worked!

Answer (score 26):

Your script syntax is valid bash and good.

Possible causes for the failure:

1. Your `bash` is not really bash but `ksh` or some other shell which doesn't understand bash's parameter substitution. Because your script looks fine and works with bash.
   Do `ls -l /bin/bash` and check it's really bash and not sym-linked to some other shell.
2. If you do have bash on your system, then you may be executing your script the wrong way like: `ksh script.sh` or `sh script.sh` (and your default shell is not bash). Since you have proper shebang, if you have bash `./script.sh` or `bash ./script.sh` should be fine.

Comment: I'd be surprised if `/bin/bash` (not `/bin/sh`) were ever linked to a different shell.

Comment: ksh is actually where most of bash's syntax extensions originated from; it *certainly* has the specific parameter expansion syntax in question. I wouldn't tend to suggest calling it out as a shell unlikely to be capable.

Answer (score 11):

Try running the script explicitly using bash command rather than just executing it as executable.

Comment: Good one. It would be helpful to add some sample output to make it more clear, by using `sh script` and `bash script`... my suggestion :)

Answer (score 8):

**Also, make sure you don't have an empty string for the first line of your script.**

i.e. make sure `#!/bin/bash` is the very first line of your script.

Answer (score 7):

Not relevant to your example, but you can also get the `Bad substitution` error in Bash for any substitution syntax that Bash does not recognize. This could be:

- Stray whitespace. E.g. `bash -c '${x }'`
- A typo. E.g. `bash -c '${x;-}'`
- A feature that was added in a later Bash version. E.g. `bash -c '${x@Q}'` before Bash 4.4.

If you have multiple substitutions in the same expression, Bash may not be very helpful in pinpointing the problematic expression. E.g.:

```
$ bash -c '"${x } multiline string
$y"'
bash: line 1: ${x } multiline string
$y: bad substitution
```

Comment: This is the first hit for `Bad substitution` so I thought I'd include the case that we ran into. (It was `@Q` in Bash 4.3 hiding in a long multi-line expression.)

Comment: This was my issue when running Bash 3.x on mac

Comment: [Prooflink](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/bash-4.4-alpha/CHANGES#L425-L426) regarding `@Q` being added in `bash-4.4`.

Answer (score 3):

I was adding a dollar sign twice in an expression with curly braces in bash:

```
cp -r $PROJECT_NAME ${$PROJECT_NAME}2
```

instead of

```
cp -r $PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}2
```

Answer (score 2):

Both - bash or dash - work, but the syntax needs to be:

```
FILENAME=/my/complex/path/name.ext
NEWNAME=${FILENAME%ext}new
```

Comment: That's a completely different operation. Also, since the OP was following good practices by using lower-case variable names (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- uppercase names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; lowercase names are reserved for application use), it behooves to do likewise.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this issue is either caused by the marked answer or you have a line or space before the bash declaration

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "+x" causes problems:

```
root@raspi1:~# cat > /tmp/btest
#!/bin/bash

jobname="job_201312161447_0003"
jobname_pre=${jobname:0:16}
jobname_post=${jobname:17}
root@raspi1:~# chmod +x /tmp/btest
root@raspi1:~# /tmp/btest
root@raspi1:~# sh -x /tmp/btest
+ jobname=job_201312161447_0003
/tmp/btest: 4: /tmp/btest: Bad substitution
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case (under ubuntu 18.04), I have mixed `$( ${} )` that works fine:

```sh
BACKUPED_NB=$(ls ${HOST_BACKUP_DIR}*${CONTAINER_NAME}.backup.sql.gz | wc --lines)
```

full example [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12830/backup-dockerise-mysql-database-from-host-volume).

Answer (score 0):

I used `#!bin/bash` as well tried all approaches like no line before or after `#!bin/bash.` 
Then also tried using +x but still didn't work.
Finally i  tried running the script `./script.sh` it worked fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
jobname="job_201312161447_0003"
jobname_post=${jobname:17}
```

root@ip-10-2-250-36:/home/bitnami/python-module/workflow_scripts# sh jaru.sh
jaru.sh: 3: jaru.sh: Bad substitution

root@ip-10-2-250-36:/home/bitnami/python-module/workflow_scripts# ./jaru.sh
root@ip-10-2-250-36:/home/bitnami/python-module/workflow_scripts#

Answer (score 0):

In my case I eventually found I had a missing } for one of the environmental variables. `${model.a` should have been `${model}.a`

The takeaway is that it may be a typo.

I am editing in vi on SCO 5.0.5 so please don't bash me for missing a syntax error.