# String substitute in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I suppose to strip down a substring in my shell script. I am trying as follows:

```
fileName="Test_VSS_TT.csv.old"
```

here i want to remove the string ".csv.old" and my

```
test=${fileName%.*}
```

but getting bad substitution error.

Comment: Did you try `test=${filename%%.*}`? `%%` returns the longest matching pattern.

Comment: But the command you tried should have removed the `.old` from your string and resulted in `TEST_VSS_TT.csv` instead of throwing the error, Have you double checked your command ? ,

Comment: My first problem is still getting same error even with %%. My system is Solaris sparc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for `test=${filename%%.*}`

the doc for parameter expansion in bash [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and in zsh [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)

`%.*` will match the first `.*` pattern, whereas `%%.*` will match the longest one

**[edit]**

if `sed` is available, you could try something like that : `echo "filename.txt.bin" | sed "s/\..*//g"` which yields `filename`

Comment: @CrazyC: what shell/version are you using ?

Comment: Bash version is 
3.2.51(1)-release

Comment: strange. Can you please post a complete copy of the command and the error message from an interactive shell?

Comment: ./mytest.sh : bad substitution. If i comment out that line then no error.

Comment: are you sure your sh is bash ? there seems to be a precedent on StackOverflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615217/bash-bad-substitution). Also, have you tried launching your script with `bash ./mytest.sh` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
$ echo $f
Test_VSS_TT.csv.old
$ test=${f%%.*}
$ echo $test
Test_VSS_TT
```

`%%` will do a longest match. So it matches from the first dot upto the last and then removes the matched characters.

Comment: My first problem is still getting same error even with %%. My system is Solaris sparc

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to extract file name without extension, then how about this?

```
$ echo ${fileName}               
Test_VSS_TT.csv.old
$ test=`echo ${fileName} |cut -d '.' -f1`
$ echo $test
Test_VSS_TT
```

Answer (score 0):

echo "Test_VSS_TT.csv.old"| awk -F"." '{print $1}'

Comment: simplest way , save the result in a variable and use it when needed

Comment: awk:syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1