# Bad substitution on bash substringing operation

Tags: bash

I am trying to get this simple function working:

```
p4edit(){
    p4 edit ${$1:25}
}
```

I read the [other popular `bad substitution` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615217/bash-bad-substitution) on SO and it did not seem to help me or be related to my problem. What am I doing wrong here? I want to cut off the first 25 characters of the argument provided to my function.

I have noticed a simple `echo ${"test":3}` fails the same way, but this succeeds:

```
test="test"
echo ${test:3}
```

I am just running this in a bash instance.

Comment: Provide a link to the referenced question, explain what is going wrong. What does "fails the same way" mean? How do you have 13K rep and not know this?

Comment: I did explain what is going wrong. You read the question I posted above and you don't know what is going wrong?

Comment: You were close with `echo ${"test":3}` -- just use `echo ${test:3}`

Comment: Did you mean `${1:25}` instead of `${$1:25}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too much money! (too many dollar signs).  Use:

```
p4edit(){
    p4 edit ${1:25}
}
```

To extract the 25th-and-onwards characters from `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

Why two times a `$` ?

```
p4edit(){
  echo ${1:25}
}
```

works fine for me. String functions in bash are a bit tricky, since they are not really consistent. But `${}` already defines, that you are looking for a variable. So only submit the name to it. There are some stringfunctions with `${#var}` but as far as I know, there is never a `$` inside a `${}`

Comment: No, there is a case where `$` is inside. I fixed the error by adding the second `$` here: `for str in ${$(someVar)//;/ } ; do` (but a result is not that I expected).