# Capitalize first letter of string in Makefile using bash 4 syntax

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make, capitalization, bash4

In bash 4 (and above), to capitalize the first letter of a string stored in variable `L1`, I can do the following:

```
L1=en
Ll1=${L1^}
echo $Ll1
```

This prints `En`.

I'm trying to do something similar within a Makefile, but I can't get the `${L1^}` syntax to work.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

L1 = en
Ll1 := $(shell echo ${L1^})

all:
    @echo $(Ll1)
```

Produces blank output.

Can I get this to work with this kind of bash syntax without resorting to tr/sed?

P.S. I do need to assign it to a variable and not echo it directly.
I'm using bash 4.3.48 and GNU make 4.1.

Comment: `$(shell echo $${$(L1)^})`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two problems in your makefile, firstly the variable L1 is defined in make and isn't accessible in your call to your shell, use:

```
$(shell L1=$(L1); echo ...)
```

to define L1 in your shell.

The dollar sign needs to be escaped to not be interpreted by make:

```
$(shell L1=$(L1); echo $${L1^})
```

Comment: This will give a bad substitution error due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20616103/4284627). To solve it you need to do `bash -c 'echo $${L1^}'` instead of just `echo $${L1^}`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck It's a good point to be aware of what `SHELL` is defined to be, as the default is somthing like `/bin/sh` which might not be bash, but in this question OP already defined `SHELL` to be `/bin/bash`